# How to call something between a bridge and a router?

Tags: networking, router, bridge, terminology, bridge-router

A proper router:

- Different IP subnetworks each sides;
- Sends packets from single MAC address;
- Does not require promiscuous mode;
- Broadcasts are not usually propogated;
- Maintains table of IP-MAC mappings on each interface.

A bridge:

- Same IP subnetwork on each side;
- Sends packets from multiple MAC addresses;
- Promiscuous mode (?);
- Broadcasts are propagated;
- Maintains one MAC-interface mappings table.

How to call this configuration:

- Same IP subnetwork on each side;
- Always sends packets from single MAC address on each network adapter;
- No promiscuous mode;
- Broadcasts are propagated;
- Maintains IP-interface mappings table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "Proxy ARP Router".

When flat class-based networks were the norm and subnetting first started appearing, if you had older hosts that didn't understand subnets, the non-subnet-aware hosts would broadcast ARP requests for any address in their classful network, assuming they were all local. So to keep those hosts from losing connectivity to hosts that are now on other subnets, the routers between subnets would have to send ARP responses *on behalf of (i.e. "as a proxy for") the hosts on the other subnets* to those non-subnet-aware hosts so the non-subnet-aware hosts would send their traffic to the router, to be forwarded to the destination hosts on the other subnets.

The idea of doing Proxy ARP has come in handy in many niche network situations ever since then. For example, if you have a VPN server and want the remote VPN clients to be on the same subnet as the Ethernet LAN that the VPN server is connected to, the VPN server will have to do Proxy ARP on behalf of the VPN clients to let Ethernet hosts know they can send traffic to the VPN server and the VPN server will forward it to the remote VPN clients.

Some network administrators leave Proxy ARP enabled on their routers to help with clients that may have been manually configured with the wrong subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

There was a device called a brouter, that did exactly that.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_router

Comment: "There was"? I expect Linux can be configured to do this with automatic editing of routing table + manual propogation of broadcasts. BTW are there already such programs or I need to implement it?

Comment: Not quite. A "brouter" or bridge/router was a router for some layer-3 protocols, but a bridge for the rest. OP's proposed box isn't doing bridging.